# Has anyone faced Cassandra issue "Maximum memory usage reached"?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm using apache cassandra-3.0.6 ,4 node cluster, RF=3, CONSISTENCY is '1', Heap 16GB.

Im getting info message in system.log as

```
INFO  [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2017-03-14 20:47:14,929 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (536870912 bytes), cannot allocate chunk of 1048576 bytes
```

don't know exactly which memory it mean and I have tried by increasing the file_cache_size_in_mb to 1024 from 512 in Cassandra.yaml file But again it immediatly filled the remaining 512MB increased and stoping the application recording by showing the same info message as

```
INFO  [SharedPool-Worker-5] 2017-03-16 06:01:27,034 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (1073741824 bytes), cannot allocate chunk of 1048576 bytes
```

please suggest if anyone has faced the same issue..Thanks!!

Bhargav

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Have you got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell with Cassandra 3.11, no matter how large you set `file_cache_size_in_mb`, you will still get this message.  The cache fills up, and writes this useless message.   It happens in my case whether I set it to 2GB or 20GB.  This may be a bug in the cache eviction strategy, but I can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

The log message indicates that the node's off-heap cache is full because the node is busy servicing reads.

The `536870912 bytes` in the log message is equivalent to 512 MB which is the default `file_cache_size_in_mb`.

It is fine to see the occasional occurrences of the message in the logs which is why it is logged at `INFO` level but if it gets logged repeatedly, it is an indicator that the node is getting overloaded and you should consider increasing the capacity of your cluster by adding more nodes.

For more info, see my post on DBA Stack Exchange -- [What does "Maximum memory usage reached" mean in the Cassandra logs?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314796/). Cheers!